# All solutions for N-Queens problem prints empty board

Tags: python, recursion, n-queens

As the title states, I've implemented the N-Queens problem for all soulutions but there is one problem, it prints an empty board. I saw a solution only where we put the printboard in an if statement but without a return in printboard i fail to see how it works`

```
#N Queens through Backtracking with all solutions

def initialize(n):
    for key in ['queen','row','col','NWtoSE','SWtoNE']:
        board[key] = {}
    
    for i in range(n):
        
        board['queen'][i] = -1
        board['row'][i] = 0
        board['col'][i] = 0
        
    for i in range (2*n-1):
        
        #Sum of NW to SE diagonal add to constant i.e (i+j) = const
        board['SWtoNE'][i] = 0
    
    for i in range (-(n-1), n):
        
        #Difference of SW to NE diagonal is constant i.e (j-i) = const
        board['NWtoSE'][i] = 0
        
def isAvailable(i, j):
    
    return (board['row'][i] == 0 and board['col'][j] == 0 and 
            board['NWtoSE'][j-i] == 0 and board['SWtoNE'][j+i] == 0)

def addQueen(i, j):
    
    board['queen'][i] = j
    board['row'][i] = 1
    board['col'][j] = 1
    board['NWtoSE'][j-i] = 1
    board['SWtoNE'][j+i] = 1

def undo(i, j):
    
    board['queen'][i] = -1
    board['row'][i] = 0
    board['col'][j] = 0
    board['NWtoSE'][j-i] = 0
    board['SWtoNE'][j+i] = 0
    
def printboard():
    
    for i in board['queen'].keys():
        
        print((i, board['queen'][i]), end = " ")
    
    print()        

def placequeen(i):
    
    n = len(board['queen'].keys())
    
    for j in range(n):
        
        
        if(isAvailable(i, j)):
            
            
            addQueen(i, j)
            
            if i == n-1:
                printboard()
            else:
                placequeen(i+1)
            undo(i,j)
    
    

board = {}
n = int(input("Enter number of queens : "))

initialize(n)
printboard()
```

The following is the solution which I don't understand
`if placequeen(0):  printboard()`

Comment: "placequeen" always returns None (because it doesn't return anything explicitly) so "if placequeen(0)" is always false. "printboard" is then only called in "placequeen" but not after it.

Comment: oh ok, I understood. So I essentially added a printboard for no reason. I could've just called placequeen(0)